# Trying to launch an .exe file from chosen directory c#

Tags: c#, exe

So my friend created a GUI using Python and he changed the file to .exe file already. So I am supposed to launch the GUI (.exe) file with c# windows through a button. And the name of my button is `'Active Rehab'`. I tried launching the GUI.exe file but I keep having this pop-up message box saying that Fatal Error is Detected and I have `"failed to execute script GUI".` Please help, I am able to open other types of files like a word document and PowerPoint. But I am just not able to launch the GUI.exe file that I want. This is my code.

```
private void ActiveRehabButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openexe = new OpenFileDialog();

    if (openexe.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string GUI = openexe.FileName;
        Process.Start(GUI);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try to specify the working directory for process

Comment: Just to be sure, when you start the .exe directly, it does work?

Comment: The executable either has to be in the same folder as the c# application or you need to specify the full path of the executable.  The process class does not inherit the environmental variable PATH which searches multiple folders for the executable.

Comment: @jdweng `OpenFileDialog.FileName` returns full path to the file.

Comment: Still if the application is calling other apps they will not be found as well as any other environmental variables.

Comment: @jdweng `OpenFileDialog.FileName` contains *full path* to the executable which by definition does not depend on environment variables. Have you visited https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392514/what-can-i-do-about-a-user-consistently-spreading-misinformation?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing what do you mean? Like I am able to open all the files but when i click on to the GUI.exe it a message box just pops up and indicate that there is a fetal error

Comment: @jdweng and how do i do that? Because all the pictures that are used in the GUI.exe file are already put into the same file as the GUI but when i try to open the GUI by itself,  a fetal error appears

Comment: You could set the environmental varaible before running the application.

Comment: I mean, can you *without using your app* start that GUI.exe? So straight from Windows Explorer. Just to make sure that that GUI.exe is not the issue, but something in the way you start it from your app, such as missing environment variables. We don't know what you already tried

Comment: @HansKeﬆing yes I am able to open the GUI.exe without using my app. But when i try to start it from my app it does not open at all. How can i do the environment variable? With the code that I have above?

Comment: Try searching for "python failed to execute script". One of the results may be helpful